# Problems while spliting pandas dataframe row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

In:

```
df
```

out:

```
         A    B        C                                             D
0  0938320  usa   amazon              orange: $ 8.00| pineapple: $2.00
1  0938320  usa  alibaba                  orange: $ 8.00| apple: $2.00
2  0938320  usa     ebay  mint: $ 8.00| watermelon: $2.00| mint: $2.00
...
n  0938320  usa   amazon                  pear: $ 8.00| bannana: $2.00
```

I would like to split by `|` and stack it into (*):

```
         A    B        C                  D
0  0938320  usa   amazon     orange: $ 8.00
1  0938320  usa   amazon   pineapple: $2.00
2  0938320  usa  alibaba     orange: $ 8.00
3  0938320  usa  alibaba       apple: $2.00
4  0938320  usa      bay       mint: $ 8.00
5  0938320  usa     ebay  watermelon: $2.00
6  0938320  usa     ebay        mint: $2.00
7  0938320  usa   amazon       pear: $ 8.00
...
8  0938320  usa   amazon     bannana: $2.00
```

So, I tried the following:

In:

```
s = df2.D.str.split("|").apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
del df2['D']
df.join(s)
```

out:

```
ValueError: Other Series must have a name
```

And:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(df2.D.str.split('|').tolist(), index=df2['A','B','C']).stack()
b = b.reset_index()[[0, 'D']] 
b.columns = ['A','B','C']
b
```

However, is not working. How can I modify the last approach in order to get (*)?. I guess that my main problem is that I do not know how to take all the columns in `index=df2['A','B','C']).stack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first set the 3 columns as index of the `DF` and perform splitting on the fourth column, `D`. Let the output obtained take the form of a dataframe using `expand=True` argument in [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]: 
        A     B         C                                              D
0  938320   usa    amazon               orange: $ 8.00| pineapple: $2.00
1  938320   usa   alibaba                   orange: $ 8.00| apple: $2.00
2  938320   usa      ebay   mint: $ 8.00| watermelon: $2.00| mint: $2.00

In [56]: df_split = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].str.split('|', expand=True)

In [57]: df_split
Out[57]: 
                                    0                   1             2
A      B    C                                                          
938320  usa  amazon    orange: $ 8.00    pineapple: $2.00          None
             alibaba   orange: $ 8.00        apple: $2.00          None
             ebay        mint: $ 8.00   watermelon: $2.00   mint: $2.00
```

Then, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) them to obtain a single wholesome column(dropping `NaNs` by default) and then rearrange it back using `reset_index`.

```
In [58]: df_split.stack().reset_index(level=[0,1,2], name='D').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[58]: 
        A     B         C                   D
0  938320   usa    amazon      orange: $ 8.00
1  938320   usa    amazon    pineapple: $2.00
2  938320   usa   alibaba      orange: $ 8.00
3  938320   usa   alibaba        apple: $2.00
4  938320   usa      ebay        mint: $ 8.00
5  938320   usa      ebay   watermelon: $2.00
6  938320   usa      ebay         mint: $2.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using `join` to combine the split data.

```
# split D and get it into long/stacked format
productsLong = pd.DataFrame({'products':
                df['D'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)})

# join the data together on the indices
df[['A', 'B', 'C']].join(productsLong)

Out[56]: 
        A    B        C            products
0  938320  usa   amazon      orange: $ 8.00
0  938320  usa   amazon    pineapple: $2.00
1  938320  usa  alibaba      orange: $ 8.00
1  938320  usa  alibaba        apple: $2.00
2  938320  usa     ebay        mint: $ 8.00
2  938320  usa     ebay   watermelon: $2.00
2  938320  usa     ebay         mint: $2.00
3  938320  usa   amazon        pear: $ 8.00
3  938320  usa   amazon      bannana: $2.00
```

*Notes*
the `rename` method was returning an error, so I cast the Series into a DataFrame in order to provide a column name. `reset_index` with the levels=1 removes the "outer" index, keeping the index of the original DataFrame (repeated properly for the join operation).